# spring-kafka: Kafka consumer isn't receiving records if I define a record producer in my application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm writing a small PoC using Spring and Spring Kafka. My goal is to have both a producer and a consumer, writing to (resp. reading from) from this topic.

I'm having a weird situation where:

- The producer is correctly producing the records (I'm able to consume them via a Python script)
- The consumer doesn't receive the records
- *But* if I remove the producer from my code and generate records via another method (e.g. with a python script), the consumer receives the records correctly.

Below is my code - it is very similar to the examples of the documentation. More precisely, the problem is coming from the fact that **the beans in *KafkaConsumerConfiguration* are not being created by Spring** (i.e. the methods constructing them are never called).

#### Producer

KafkaProducerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:32768");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

MessageSender.java

```
@Component
public class MessageSender {
    final static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MessageSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onConstruct() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("Sending messages...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            kafkaTemplate.send("mytopic", "this is a message");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        kafkaTemplate.flush(); // NOTE: no changes if I move this call in the loop
        log.info("Done sending messages");
    }
}
```

#### Consumer

KafkaConsumerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:32768");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-service");
        return props;
    }
}
```

**MyMessageListener.java**

```
@Service
public class MyMessageListener {
    final static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyMessageListener.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void onConstruct() {
        log.info("Message listener started");
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic")
    public void onMessageReceived(String message) {
        log.info("Got message: "+ message);
    }
}
```

Here's the log generated by the application, for reference: https://pastebin.com/BY783jiL. As you can see, the consumer beans are not being created (otherwise there would be a block `ConsumerConfig values: ...`.

Here are a few things I tried without success:

- Putting the producer and consumer configuration in the same configuration class
- Changing the name of the beans in KafkaConsumerConfiguration (and add the annotation attribute `containerFactory = "myBeanName"` on the `MyMessageListener.onMessageReceived` method)
- Changing the name of the class `KafkaConsumerConfiguration` to something else
- Adding a non kafka-related `@Bean` in my `KafkaConsumerConfiguration` to see if it would get created (it does)

Versions: Spring Boot 1.5.9, Spring-Kafka: 1.1.7.

I've been tearing my hair out for a few hours now, any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the issue. `MessageSender.onConstruct` is actually taking a lot of time to execute (100 seconds), and during the meantime it is preventing Spring from creating the other beans.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> kafkaTemplate.send("mytopic", "this is a message");
> ```

You should NEVER start interacting with external services in a `@PostConstruct` method - you need to wait for the application to be built before doing so.

Implement `SmartLifecyle`, return `true` for `isAutoStartup` and move that code to `start()`.

Or implement `ApplicationListener<ConstextRefreshedEvent>` and do the sends when you get the event.

Either way will ensure that the application is ready.